# How to get each http body updates on angular Http request?

Tags: ajax, angular, http, express, request

I'm using an express api (my back-end) and an angular app (my front-end).

One express js end point (let's call it '/foo') is processing a lot of files,
i send data using res.write() after each treatment so the http response body is update. 
I would like to get this update on my angular app. 
I was using ajax in a previous version and it worked fine with ajax call :

```
 xhrFields: {
                    // Getting on progress streaming response
                    onprogress: function(e)
                    {
                        var progressResponse;
                        var response = e.currentTarget.response;
                        if(lastResponseLength === false)
                        {
                            progressResponse = response;
                            lastResponseLength = response.length;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            progressResponse = response.substring(lastResponseLength);
                            lastResponseLength = response.length;
                        }
                        actualResponse += progressResponse
            }
```

Unfortunatly i found nothing to get partial http body. I tried to use 'reportProgress' Parameter but it's not working.

For some more context my front-end angular code: 
service.ts :

```
setHolidaysDirectory(holidaysKey: string, path: string): Observable<Object>{
   const setHolidayDirectoryStreamHttpRequest =
      new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8089/holidays/pictures/edit', { 'key': holidaysKey,
    'path': path
  }, {headers: this._httpHeaders, reportProgress: true, responseType: 'text'});

// pipe stream answer
return this._http.request(setHolidayDirectoryStreamHttpRequest);
```

}

and my component just call the service and subscribe :

```
this._holidaysService
            .setHolidaysDirectory(key, finalHolidaysForm.path)
            .subscribe((stream) => {
              console.log('new answer');
              console.log(stream);
            }, error => console.log(error));
```

But unfortunatly i got empty answer and all the http body is recovered after res.end() (server side)

Can anyone help pls !

Thank a lot !

Comment: Hello, could you please clarify what you mean when you say the Angular code is not working? Could you add some of your Angular code to provide some context? For example, how are you processing your stream (RxJS operators for example)?

Comment: Have a look there https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events

Comment: I just edit the question :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Any update guys ?